# Place one of three values in a cell at radom

Tags: excel, vba

I had a code that would place 1 or 2 values in a cell at random (The values were either "SF" or "BM") and I used to do it this way

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = IIf(Rnd() > 0.5, "BM", "JC")
```

The problem is that I want to add a new third value "KS" and doing the following doesn't work

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = IIf(Rnd() > 0.5, "BM", "JC", "KS")
```

How can I place one of these 3 values at random in a cell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is a way I would do it

```
Dim value As String

Select Case Int(Rnd() * 3)
    Case 0
        value = "BM"
    Case 1
        value = "JC"
    Case 2
        value = "KS"
End Select

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = value
```

I generate a random integer between 0 and 2 using Int(Rnd() * 3), and then use a Select Case statement to assign the corresponding value ("BM", "JC", or "KS") to the value variable. Finally, the code places the value in cell A1 of Sheet1.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this work for you:

In order to place one of three values at random in a cell, you can create a function that generates a random number between 1 and 3 and then determines the value based on the number.

For instance, if the random number generated is 1, the value in the cell would be "BM". If the number is 2, the value would be "JC", and if the number is 3, the value would be "KS". You can use the following code to accomplish this via [`WorksheetFunction.Choose()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/choose-function-fc5c184f-cb62-4ec7-a46e-38653b98f5bc):

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1 ").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Choose(Int(Rnd()*3+1)," BM","JC","KS")
```

Answer (score 2):

Please, try the next way:

```
Sub RndOfMore3Strings()
    Dim arrCrit(), arrPos As Long
    arrCrit = Array("BM", "JC", "KS") 'you can use here as many criteria you need, withoout adapting the code...
    Randomize
    'returning the element position in the above array:
    arrPos = Int((UBound(arrCrit) - LBound(arrCrit) + 1) * Rnd + LBound(arrCrit))
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = arrCrit(arrPos)
End Sub
```